# Access AzureAd registered API from a B2C registered Web App

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-b2c

We have an Azure AD B2C registered web app and an Azure AD registered Web API - is it possible to make authenticated calls to the Azure AD Web API from the Azure B2C Web app? Can it be done?

We have tried a few different ways but not having much luck - including Access Control Lists but it doesn't accept the token passed as says it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You must register two applications in the Azure AD B2C directory to enable your app to sign in with Azure AD B2C and call a web API.

- Your app can sign in with Azure AD B2C via the *web, mobile, or SPA application* registration. The *Application ID*, also known as the *client ID*, is generated during the app registration process and uniquely identifies your application (for example, *App ID: 1*).
- Your app can use the *web API* registration to call a protected web API. - The web API permissions (scopes) are exposed as part of the registration . The *Application ID* is generated during the app registration process, and it uniquely identifies your web API (for example, _App ID: 2 ).

For more information, please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient).